# Need to create SVN repository and integrate in eclipse.

Tags: eclipse, svn

Need to create SVN repository and integrate in eclipse. The repository should be shared among the ppl connected to my LAN. Can anyone help me on this. Steps Required?

Comment: Have you already done some research? This is not a single command, thus, we may help you on a particular problem if you add where you're stuck, what error do you encounter, what you don't understand, etc.... Also, please a a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use either [Subversive](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider) or [Subclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse) for that.